# How to limit datepicker's max date to today?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

The questions is in the Title. I have two datepickers, from and to. I want to limit the from datepicker to the current date. How do I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the maxDate options : http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-maxDate

> Set a maximum selectable date via a Date object or as a string in the
>   current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a
>   string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for
>   weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +1w'), or null for no limit.

For example : `$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", new Date() );`