# How to make furture dates unavailable with datepicker

Tags: php, javascript, datepicker

I am using a datepicker off the web, jsDatePick.jquery.min.1.3. it works 100% but how do I limit dates to today and earlier, so tomorrow is not available to pick.

code for script is below and calls jsDatePick.jquery.min.1.3.js to process.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"collectdate",
            dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d",
            yearsRange:[2013,2020],
            */
            /*
            cellColorScheme:"beige",
            dateFormat:"%m-%d-%Y",
            imgPath:"img/",
            weekStartDay:1*/
        });
    };
</script>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. Please let me know if you require the js file syntax, this is quite a big file so too much code to place on this question.

Thanks as always,

Comment: I guess this will help you....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010448/how-to-limit-datepickers-max-date-to-today

Comment: @PavanK : It is not a jQuery UI datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "limitToToday" option for the required functionality :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
        limitToToday:true,
        useMode:2,
        target:"collectdate",
        dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d",
        yearsRange:[2013,2020],
        */
        /*
        cellColorScheme:"beige",
        dateFormat:"%m-%d-%Y",
        imgPath:"img/",
        weekStartDay:1*/
    });
};
</script>
```